# Trying to determine appropriate beam size for a header on a large sliding glass door

Tags: doors, exterior, beam, load

I am considering installing a large sliding glass door in an Exterior wall with load from both interior 2 story slopped ceiling joists/rafters (new door going into 9' end) and on the other side is an exterior patio cover which is built similar to an exterior room i.e 2x8 on 16c. The rough opening would be approx 15'. Looking at calculators it 2- 2x12's may do the job for that span but not positive that is the answer. Looking for recommendations engineered or otherwise so that I do not get any inflection considering it is a sliding door. Thank you very much

Comment: What is the span of the roof from the patio side that rests on this wall? Also, what is the reference to 2 stories? What are the spans of the roof and walls that rest on this wall? If the opening is going to be 15’, then what is reference for “9’ end” ?

Comment: Thanks for probing questions. Exterior patio roof is 16' off the exterior wall. The two stories reference is the new door wall is 9' floor to ceiling and the other side of room (other end of ceiling rafters) is about 20' floor to ceiling. Not sure that makes a big difference or not.

Comment: If you could include a sketch (doesn't have to be to scale, just write on the dimensions), that would go a _long_ way toward helping people understand your layout.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure I completely understand the layout, but you can tell me where I’m wrong.

There is no floor load resting on this wall/beam.

The roof load has a span of 20’, so 10’ rests on the wall/ beam and the other 10’ rests on another wall. So, depending on where you’re located, normal snow loads range from 25 lbs. per square foot (psf) to 35 psf. I’ll use 35 psf.

Therefore, the roof load is 10’ x 35 psf = 350 per linear foot (plf).

Plus the roof load from the patio roof is 16’ / 2 x 35 psf = 280 plf.

The wall load on the new beam will be about 10’ high (2 storey minus the 9’ sliding door height). Most walls weigh about 10 psf to 15 psf. I’ll use 15 psf. Therefore, the wall load on the new beam is 10’ x 15 psf = 150 plf.

So the total load on the beam is

350 plf + 280 plf + 150 plf = 780 plf.

So, depending on the species and grade of lumber, a 6x14 beam can span 15’ and carry 780 plf.

I used SPF lumber with a “Select” grade. I noticed you were hoping to use 2- 2x12’s, so I presume you are working in a 2x4 wall. If you want to use 2x12’s, I’d use 5-2x12’s to span 15’ and support 780 plf.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. There is no floor resting on this wall just roof on either side. The interior side of the wall is supporting the ceiling rafters, the room has a vaulted ceiling 9' floor to ceiling wall in question and approx 18-20' floor to ceiling on the other end of the vault which is at center of home. This room is only 14' from exterior wall to the high point in the vault. So it is fairly steep pitch on the roof.

Comment: The porch cover on the exterior is 16' off exterior wall. It was built using 2x8 - 16"oc and attached to the facia with simpson hangers. Roofed with standard roof decking and composite shingles.

Comment: We live in Austin TX.. so snow is very rare. Except for the blizzard of 2021 :-)

Comment: The pitch on the porch roof is minimal but certainly not flat.

Comment: For your location, I think I’d reduce the load to 20 psf. (Can’t go below that because of your recent snow last year. We don’t design for the “normal” it’s always the “exceptional”.) so, your total patio roof load is 8’ x 20 psf = 160 plf plus 14/2 x 20 = 140 plf plus 150 plf wall load = 450 plf. So, with that reduced load, a 4x12 with a grade of “Select Structural” will support 455 plf spanning 15’, using an increase for “short duration loading”.

Comment: Thanks Lee Sam- So the original calculator was not too far off. It said 2 - 2x12 and your recommendation is a single 4x12 with a grade for select structural. Is LVL an option too? Same 4x12?

Comment: Yes, LVL is fine...without looking it up...because LVL’s are stronger than cut timbers. Make sure get the highest and best tread of 4x12, because it barely makes it with the highest grade. Oh, and install with camber side up.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help!!

Comment: @BRIANCDURNELL if you'll please take a moment to take the [tour], you'll see that the appropriate way to say "thank you" is to click the up vote arrow on all answers that help you and to click the check mark on the answer that helps you the most.